# Dynamic URL issue on JSP in data table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate.

In JSP page I am using data table in which there are 3 columns ie App, Res, and id. The values of three columns are coming dynamically and these three are link.

For Example :  Res is "xyz" and App is "abc" and user clicks on this xyz link then my url would be like `/admin/<Res>/<App>` so url become `/admin/xyz/abc`.

In controller, I am taking it as a `@PathVariable` and @RequestMapping is /admin/{res_name}/{app_name} so `Res` and `App` become available in controller.

My Problem :

1) If Res is "xvf\y" and App is "abc" and if user clicks on link then url become `/admin/xvf/y/abc` so it doesn't match with my controller request mapping. Hence , controller method is not getting called.

2) If Res is "xvf\y" and App is "ab\c" then also issue will occur.

How to handle this. Please help.

Comment: encode the data that you expect as path parameter.

Comment: can you please provide some details. how to do this.

Comment: Please help friends...

Comment: post your code where you create url appending RES and APP?

Answer (score 0):

it should be URL Encoded so `xvf\y` is transformed to `xvf%5Cy`

Use e.g. URLEncoder.encode("xvf\y") (or pass desired encoding as the second param)